# MinGW32, неопределенный символ LockWorkStation()

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw

Проблема следующая.

Разрабатываю под **Windows 10**, использую компилятор **MinGW32** и IDE **Code::Blocks**. Хочу использовать функцию **LockWorkStation()**, но компилятору не удается найти определение этого символа. Хотя, если перейти через редактор кода к этому определению, оно располагается в **winuser.h**.

Если верить **MSDN**, требуемая мне функция находится в **user32.lib**.

Такого файла в директории с компилятором **MinGW32** мне найти не удалось, поэтому я попробовал использовать **user32.lib** из других расположений, так как у меня имеется несколько компиляторов. Проблему это не решило.

Я пробовал использовать файл **libuser32.a**, который находится в директории компилятора **MinGW32**, но это не помогло.

Я окончательно запутался. Подскажите, что мне необходимо сделать, чтобы **MinGW32** позволил мне использовать требуемую функцию?

Comment: Все проще, в опциях линкера добавьте `-luser32` и он сам все подставит, это стандартная библиотека, и к ней есть .а файл в самом mingw, директория lib внутри.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все проще, в опциях линкера добавьте `-luser32` и он сам все подставит, это стандартная библиотека, и к ней есть `.а` файл в самом `mingw`, директория lib внутри. Формат `.lib` файлов не подходят для `mingw`, но, в **c::b** можно указывать `.dll` напрямую, путем выбора файла в опциях линкера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее про mingw и dll http://www.mingw.org/wiki/createimportlibraries , про mingw (gcc) и синтаксис подключения библиотек http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Как оказалось, все еще проще. Некоторые функции WinAPI в файлах заголовков находятся под условной компиляцией. Это связано с тем, что функции вводились в WinAPI постепенно. Поэтому для их использования нужно определить соответствующие макроконстанты.

Comment: Да, конечно, надо не забывать перед `includes` добавлять `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`